# Communications from Rails to Adobe flex application, suggestions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

Im interested in communicating from a ruby on rails app with a flex app.
Basically I would supply some data from the rails app to the flex application to be used ( like variable names, and data) later on I also need some form of protection so only logged in users in the ruby app can use the flex application.

I plan to build my flex app in flash builder 6.5 premium.
The rails app is 3.1

Ive searched online for some good resources but only find old gems and outdated blog posts. 
Anyone can recommend me some good resources on flex and ruby on rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For communication between the two - look at [RubyAMF](https://github.com/rubyamf/rubyamf).  This allows for you to use RemoteObject calls from Flex to seamlessly communicate with Ruby.  As far as ensuring only authenticated users of your Ruby application can access the Flex application - this would be just like protecting any static asset (but in this case, you would protect the SWF file).

Here is an example tutorial using RubyAMF: http://panscendo.com/beginners-tutorial-to-rubyamf-with-restful-rails/

Comment: Very useful, actually i came across it a hour later while digging around for flex and rails. Do you perhaps know of a more recent tutorial? Ive looked at the amfdemo app on github but a writeup would be nice. Seems not many people use Flex and Rails together these days. thx